# PHP magic methods in various scopes

Tags: php, oop, scope, magic-methods

I've been reading up on [PHP magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) and trying to better understand them. From the PHP manual it states:

> The overloading methods are invoked when interacting with properties or methods that have not been declared or are not visible in the current scope.

I've read up on what "not [visible](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)" means:

> The visibility of a property, a method or (as of PHP 7.1.0) a constant can be defined by prefixing the declaration with the keywords public, protected or private.

So consider the class below:

```
<?php
    class MyClass{
        private $x = 1;
        protected $y = 2;
        public $z = 3;

        public __construct(){}

        function __get($name){
           switch(true){
             case ($name == 'x'):
                 return 4;
             case ($name == 'y'):
                 return 5;
             case ($name == 'z'):
                 return 6;
             case ($name == 'w'):
                 return 0;
           }
        }

        function sum(){
            return $this->x + $this->y + $this->z;
        }

    }
?>
```

So considering the snippets above regarding "visible" and "scope", under what context will the `__get` magic method get invoked and when will it not?

If I instantiate a new object: `$myclass = new MyClass()`, will `$myclass->sum()` return `6` or `15` or something else?

What if I call the `$myclass->x`, `$myclass->y`, `$myclass->z`, will the results be `4`, `5` and `3` since `x` and `y` are technically not "visible"?

I assume calling `$myclass->w` will return `0` regardless of scope since it wasn't ever defined as a property of the class to begin with, is that right?

Comment: *"public **function** __construct(){}"*. The closing `}` of the `switch` statement is missing. And it is more clear to use it as `switch ($name) { case 'x': return 4; case 'y': return 5; }`

Comment: Here is a free hint: dont use magic getters an setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So considering the snippets above regarding "visible" and "scope", under what context will the `__get` magic method get invoked and when will it not?

The `__get` method will be invoked when a property is accessed that does not exist on the object, or when a property is accessed from a scope from which it is not accessible. For instance, `$obj->foo` will always trigger `__get`, and `$obj->x` will trigger `__get` when called from outside the class.

> If I instantiate a new object: `$myclass = new MyClass()`, will `$myclass->sum()` return 6 or 15 or something else?

It'll return 6 (`1 + 2 + 3`). `$this->x`, `->y`, and `->z` are all accessible from within the class, so the `__get` method is not triggered here.

> What if I call the `$myclass->x`, `$myclass->y`, `$myclass->z`, will the results be 4, 5 and 3 since x and y are technically not "visible"?

Correct.

> I assume calling `$myclass->w` will return 0 regardless of scope since it wasn't ever defined as a property of the class to begin with, is that right?

Correct, so long as you have not explicitly assigned a value to `$myclass->w`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass {
    private $x = 1;
    protected $y = 2;
    public $z = 3;
    // ...
}
```

Inside the code of `MyClass` class, all instance properties (`$x`, `$y` and `$z`) are visibile. The `sum()` function sees them and when it uses them there is no need to call `__get()`.

This also happens if the code tries to access the `protected` or `private` properties of another object of the same class. For example:

```
class MyClass {
    private $x = 1;
    protected $y = 2;
    public $z = 3;

    public function copyFrom(MyClass $that) {
        $this->x = $that->x;
        $this->y = $that->y;
        $this->z = $that->z;
    }
}

$a = new MyClass();
$b = new MyClass();
$b->copyFrom($a);
```

The `copyFrom()` method has access to all properties of the `$that` object (because it is of the same class as `$this`) and `__get()` is not invoked.

But for this code:

```
$a = new MyClass();
echo($a->x + $a->y + $a->z);
```

the magic method `__get()` is invoked twice, for `$a->x` and `$a->y` because these properties are not visible from the code outside the `MyClass` class.

---

As a general rule, if the class does not define the `__get()` method, when a property that is not visible is accessed for reading, the interpreter triggers the fatal error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property MyClass::$x

The presence of `__get()` suppresses the error. `__get()` is invoked instead and the value it returns is used. If `__get()` does not return a value (no matter why), [`NULL`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) is used instead (this is the standard PHP behaviour of functions).